# change the content of the page from the select operation in laravel

Tags: laravel, select, operation

i have a select operation and there is three select form in it 
so when i select one of them it should change the content of the page or the page
i mean this modal should change the body to another form when i select form 2 or 3 in the same modal

### here is the code

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Chose Form</h4>

                <div class="como">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option >select form</option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @yield('formbody')
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect text-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
form 1
@section('formbody')
    any html code............ form1
@endsection

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
form 2
@section('formbody')
    any html code............ form2
@endsection
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
form 3
@section('formbody')
    any html code............ form3
@endsection

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If you don't want the page to reload, you will need ajax to do so.

Comment: Simplest way to do it is to include all forms (three forms for your example) in your modal-body and switch between forms by toggling show/hide. For this approach you will need to use some of Javascript/jQuery code to apply appropriate class to each form. For an example, when you select option 2, class .hidden should apply to forms 1 and 3 (class .shown should apply to form 2) and when you select option 3, class .hidden should apply to forms 1 and 2 (class .shown should apply to form 3). It's pretty basic approach but it depends on your needs. If you need a live example, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you should use onchange attribute inside your select and decide your action route

```
<form action="filter" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <select class="form-control" name='slcrecom' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
        <option value="-">select form</option>
        <option value="0">1</option>
        <option value="1">2</option>
        <option value="2">3</option>
    </select>
    <noscript>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </noscript>
</form>
```

Make sure that select option above is always included and show into each layout and decide your layout blade for option 1, 2, and 3. In your controller make return view according to your option selected, like this.

```
public function filter(Request $request)
    {
      $slcrecom = $request->input("slcrecom");
      $arrayLayout = array('views.layout1','views.layout2','views.layout3' );

      return view($arrayLayout[$slcrecom]);
    }
```

hope this will help you, any question please comment

Comment: con you explain more clearly i'm not pro in this things

Comment: con you explain more clearly i'm not pro in this things this is the for example the name of the body that i wanna include it in the modal form1.blade.php / form2.blade.php / form3.blade.php so how dose it work  i put this function filter in HomeController but it still not working  can u explain more deeply :)

Comment: hmm... have you change the content of array() according to your layout name and set your routes to post variable into filter() function?